# How to use mysql query for all value of my table?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I have a MySQL query for ask category quantity to Prestashop, but I cannot extend it to all categories.

I use categories value from `$_POST` variable, but I'd like to extend it to all categories value:

```
$query_quant = "SELECT SUM(ps_stock_available.quantity) as tot FROM ps_stock_available LEFT JOIN ps_category_product ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_category_product.id_product WHERE ps_category_product.id_category = '$cat'";
```

Maybe I need to use `mysql_fetch_array`, but I want to know how can I assign all category value to `$cat` ?

---

I tried to use this:

```
$query_category = "SELECT id_category FROM ps_category";

$result_category = mysql_query($query_category);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_category))
{

$categoria = $row['id_category'];
```

But I have error 404

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use in statement to pass all categories into your query

```
    $query_quant = "SELECT SUM(ps_stock_available.quantity) as tot FROM ps_stock_available 
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_category_product.id_product WHERE 
ps_category_product.id_category in ('$cat1','$cat2','$cat3','$cat4')";
```

As you mentioned in comment if you want to have the sum for each category use group by

```
    $query_quant = "SELECT SUM(ps_stock_available.quantity) as tot,ps_category_product.id_category as cat FROM ps_stock_available 
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_category_product.id_product WHERE 
ps_category_product.id_category in ('$cat1','$cat2','$cat3','$cat4') group by ps_category_product.id_category";
```

Comment: I need SUM for each category
SUM1 -> $cat1
SUM2 -> $cat2
SUM2 -> $cat3

Comment: I have added the query for that, upvote if my answer helps you

Comment: Ok thanks, it works. But I have more 200 values, i cannot insert '$cat1','$cat2','$cat3','$cat4'... ecc.. How can I insert all categories value? thanks

Comment: just append to a common variable and then pass that variable to query

Comment: my difficulty is to define the variable of each individual category

Comment: no need variable for each category, just follow as below
$category.="'value1',";
use this inside a loop and finally remove that last comma

Comment: i tried to have single $category

$query_category = "SELECT id_category FROM ps_category";

$result_category = mysql_query($query_category);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_category))
{

$categoria = $row['id_category'];

Comment: Please post as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Sir if the categories coming as comma separate you can use "IN" cause for checking category ids. Right now in your query you are only using "=" condition for category It means only one category will be extracted. I hope you get it